# How to use circuitikz to plot the below figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am new to tikz, so I definitely have no idea to plot the below figure with circuitikz, especially the center parts.

Can anyone help me?
[image: a electrical circuits]

---

**EDIT**:

According to the documentation of circuitikz, I wrote some codes which met some parts of the graph. Howerver, it is far away from the final one.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw[color=black, thick]
   (0,0) to [R,l=$R_1$,] (6,0)
   to [L,l=$V_1$,] (6,6)
   to [short] (0,6)
   to [battery1, l=$E$] (0,0)
   (3,6.5) node[]{\large{I}}

   (14,0) to [short] (8,0)
   to [L, l=$V_2$,] (8,6)
   to [R,l=$R_2$,] (14,6)
   to [C, l=$C$,] (14,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which likes:

[image]

Please give me some modifications, many thanks! @darthbith

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post an attempt, e.g. without the magnet in the center?

Comment: For a one off, the center can be drawn using regular Tikz commands. Unless you can use a regular transformer, then it is simple(r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt to the OP's image where `decoration` with coil is used. To keep the lines nicely connected, orthogonal coordinates `(<a-|b>)`, meaning y-coordinate of < a >  and x coordinate of < b >, is used in many places.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document} 

\begin{circuitikz}[american, decoration={coil}]
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm] circle[radius=1.5cm];
\draw [->,thick](0,0) -- node[midway, left]{R}(80:1.5) ;
\draw [->,thick](0,0) --node[midway,below]{r}(30:1); 
\begin{scope}
\draw[decorate, decoration={aspect=0.4, segment length=3mm, amplitude=5mm}]
(1.25,-0.8) coordinate (a) --node[midway,right=0.5cm]{$V_2$} + (0,2) coordinate (b);
\draw[decorate, decoration={aspect=0.4, segment length=5mm, amplitude=5mm}]
(-1.25,-0.8) coordinate (c) --node[midway,left=0.5cm]{$V_1$} + (0,2) coordinate (d);
\end{scope}
% left circuit
\draw (-5,-1.0) coordinate (e1) to[battery,l=E] (-5,1.0) coordinate(e2);
\draw (e1) to[R,l=$R_1$,*-*] (e1-|c) --(c)node[below=0.5cm]{$N_1$};
\draw(e2)-- (d-|e2) to[short,i>=$I$] (d);
% right circuit
\draw (5,1) coordinate(e3) to[C=C,v=$V$,-*] (5,-1) coordinate (e4);
\draw  (b) to[R=$R_2$,i=$i$,-*] (b-|e3)--(e3);
\draw   (e4) to[short] (a|-e4)--(a) node[below=0.5cm]{$N_2$};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, great!! It is really what I need. Thanks very much!